# No desktop or window frame context menus

Tags: x11, menu, fluxbox

I'm running fluxbox without any DE. For some reason I lost the ability to raise the desktop and window frame context menus with the right mouse button.

I found that fluxbox did not place a "fluxbox" file into /user/share/menu/ as it should. Creating it by hand did not help. The other files there look OK as do the files in ~/.fluxbox, including the menu file.

I ran # update-menus with no effect

Perhaps unrelated, but the menu problem coincided with a problem configuring the nvidia-persistenced package. The package is installed but only partially configured. When I reinstall it I get this:

Setting up nvidia-persistenced (460.32.03-1) ...
Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
nvidia-persistenced failed to initialize. Check syslog for more details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nvidia-persistenced, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-persistenced (--configure):
installed nvidia-persistenced package post-installation script subprocess retu>

There's no report of an error in syslog.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was a faulty mouse. I should have tried another right from the start, but it just never occurred to me that mouses could fail. Sorry
to burden you with my oversight. It may come with my age (86).